# How do I perform error propagation of a polynomial function?

Tags: error, polynomial, error-propagation

I'm trying to perform error propagation for some photometry code I'm writing, but I'm having some trouble with it!

I have a value $x$ that I draw from a distribution with standard deviation $\sigma_x$, $x = \mu_x \pm \sigma_x$. I feed $x$ into a polynomial function,

$f(x) = \sum_i c_i x^i$

How do I find the standard deviation $\sigma_{f(x)}$? I understand how to perform error propagation for the sum of two variables, but for some reason polynomial error propagation is tripping me up.

Comment: As you are a new contributor, here is a suggestion: if an answer actually solves your problem, you should accept it. This way the thread is marked as "answered" (green) by the StackExchange sowftware.

Answer (score 3):

There are (at least) three different approaches to compute the variance of $f(x)$:

1. Gauss' law of error propagation, which is in this case $(\Delta f)^2\approx \left(\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_{x=\mu_x}\right)^2 (\Delta x)^2$
2. The Jackknife Variance: $\sigma_{JK}^2=\frac{n-1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (f_{(i)} - f_{(.)})^2$, where $f_{(i)}^2$ is the value of $f$ computed with sample $i$ omitted, and $f_{(.)}$ is the mean of these leave-one-out values.
3. A Bootstrap estimate of the variance, which is a Monte Carlo method and thus yields a random value, i.e. two researchers starting with the same data will obtain (somewhat) different results.

**Edit:** Method 1 assumes that $f(x)\approx f(\mu_x)+f'(\mu_x)(x-\mu_x)$ in the region $\pm 2\sigma_x$ around $x=\mu_x$, which you can check graphically. Note that if this does not hold and the function $f$ is not odd around $x=\mu_x$, the approximation (which you presumably use) $\mu_f\approx f(\mu_x)$ does not hold either.

Methods 2&3 are only applicable, if $\mu_x$ and $\sigma_x$ are empirical values and you still have the data $x_1,\ldots,x_n$. If these are theoretical values and all you have is $\mu_x$ and $\sigma_x$, but you are pretty sure that $x$ is normally distributed, then you can follow the suggestion in the comment by @whuber and calculate $\mu_f$ and $\sigma_f^2$ numerically from their exact definitions:

$$\mu_f=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\,\varphi_{\mu_x,\sigma_x}(x)\,dx \quad\mbox{ and }\quad\sigma_f^2 =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (f(x)-\mu_f)^2\,\varphi_{\mu_x,\sigma_x}(x)\,dx$$

where $\varphi$ is the probability density of the normal distribution. Apart from a proper numerical integration, you can also use a Monte Carlo approach: simulate normally distrbuted $x_i$ and compute the mean value and variance of $f(x_i)$. This is very slow to converge compared to proper numerical methods, but it has the advatnage that you also obtain an estimate of the distribution of $f$ and can compute confidence intervals therefrom. The confidence intervals $\mu_f\pm 2\sigma_f$ will have poor coverage probability, if the distribution of $f$ deviates considerably from normality.

Comment: Thank you for the response! My research mentor had me finding the error via bootstrapping, but that was really computationally intensive. I'll use Gauss' law for that now! To clarify, if $f(x) = x^2$, then $\sigma_{f(x)} = 2f(x)\frac{\sigma_x}{x}$ -- meaning it would change as $f(x)$ changes?

Comment: Be careful in applying the first solution: it will be misleading near critical points of $f.$  Provided $f$ is approximately linear within $\pm 2\Delta x$ of the argument of interest, you'll be fine.  And yes, the error changes as $f$ changes because $f$ is nonlinear whenever its degree is $2$ or greater.  There's a fourth solution: use numeric integration.  How you do this depends on precisely what you mean by the "error" in how you have computed it in the first place.

Comment: The specific definition of the error isn't up to me! I'm given the magnitudes and errors of Gaia survey data in its specific filter bands, and I'm applying saturation corrections to our data, but I need to figure out the new error of the corrected magnitudes after I do it.

And ah, that's good to know! I do know that $\sigma_x \ll x$ for all of these cases ($\sigma_x$ is on the order of 0.01 magnitudes, while $x$ is on the order of 10 magnitudes, so I'm not *too* worried about this situation, but it's still good to test for.

Comment: Whether or not you have control over how the error is defined, you need to understand what it really means.  Presumably there are metadata available that tell you that.

Comment: Yes, the formula for the case $f(x)=x^2$ is correct. I have edited the answer and added an elaboration of whubers suggestion of numerical integration.